# AMP pages adding Google Anayltics AmpAnalytics Errors

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I am following simple guide by https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/

Trying to add Pageviews GA code, but facing these two errors in console:

```
amp-analytics-0.1.max.js:243 AmpAnalytics analytics1 Analytics config could not be parsed. Is it in a valid JSON format? SyntaxError: Unexpected token /

AmpAnalytics analytics1 No triggers were found in the config. No analytics data will be sent.
```

Anyone have faced these errors and knows the fix, I have followed their docs as instructed but still facing above two issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it resolved, make sure you remove those comments from the sample code and errors will be no more.

i.e. you remove  comments from following code i.e. delete "// Replace with your property ID."

and // Trigger names can be any string. trackPageview is not a required name.

```html
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"  // Replace with your property ID.
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": {  // Trigger names can be any string. trackPageview is not a required name.
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

So it i will become this :

```html
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y" 
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": { 
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```